# Rails 4: single-table inheritance and NOT using class name as "type"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, namespaces, data-migration, sti

I have several items that I want to lump into a single `lookups` table instead of having 20+ separate tables, each with the same attributes:

- countries
- states
- email_types
- phone_types
- address_types
- etc...

In Rails I just add the `type` column to the `lookups` table and it "magically" works.

However, I have namespaced some of the models for developer ease-of-use, as it was getting a little chaotic:

```
# app/models/lookup.rb
class Lookup < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# app/models/lookups/country.rb
class Lookups::Country < Lookup
end
```

So when I `Lookups::Country.create(name: "Italy")`, it stores a `type` of `"Lookups::Country"`.

But as all good developers, I end up doing some refactoring, and instead of having all the lookups thrown into a single `app/models/lookups` namespace, I want to break them up into their various elements:

```
# app/models/addresses/country.rb
class Addressess::Country < Lookup
end
```

The sole reason to change the namespace was to re-organize the project as it grew larger and larger.

So when I `Addressess::Country.create(name: "Italy")` now, it stores a `type` of `"Addressess:Country"`.  The problem is now there are 2 "types" of countries in the `lookups` table.

Basically, I just "lost" my data because I moved a model to a different namespace.  I would have to go and update all the `"Lookups::Country"` records to have a type of `"Addressess::Country"`.

Is there any way to avoid this?  I will be moving models around frequently until they are organized maturely, and cannot afford to have to do a DB update/migration every time I move a file around to make life simpler for a developer.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the sti_name class method for each model might work.

Try this -

```
# app/models/addresses/country.rb
class Addressess::Country < Lookup
    def self.sti_name
        "Address"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: https://gist.github.com/vamdt/75aca125883a88a9f1fd
(see code)